# Criteria Restriction by date field

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 tables, `Partner` and `Visit`. A partner can have many visits, also various in same day.
I need to create a `Criteria` restriction to know how many **days** the `Partner` has visits since a given date. So, 2 or more visits in same date must be only one.

Can this be done only by `Criteria` and `Restrictions`??

I can get all visits from a date with a criteria like:

```
Criteria criteria = buildCriteria();
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(DBConstants.VISIT_COL_VISITOR, partnerVisitor));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(DBConstants.VISIT_COL_DATE, startDate));
```

But now, to filter repeated days, I need something like:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.unique(DBConstants.VISIT_COL_DATE));
```

Any idea?

***EDIT:*** @user23123412 @netik

```
Visit.java

private Integer id;
private Date date;
private Partner visitor;

// getters + setters
```

`Visit` table rows related to partner 1:

| ID | VISITOR | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10/10/2014 16:20 |
| 20 | 1 | 10/10/2014 18:00 |
| 45 | 1 | 12/10/2014 16:20 |
| 71 | 1 | 12/10/2014 19:40 |
| 89 | 1 | 16/10/2014 11:20 |

The answer I need after the query is a `Visit` count in **different days** since a given `date`.

I.E.: If i launch a query with `visitor = 1` and `startDate = 12/10/2014` the result **MUST** be 2, cause row `id = 45` and `id = 71` have different visits in a same day, so it's only ONE day.

Comment: Yes you can achieve this using criteria, do you have oneToMany relationship on your JPA?

Comment: Yes, `OneToMany`relationship is in `Partner` which can have many `Visits`... but this is not important here, `Date` has no relationship with `Partner` and can be repeated several times with different hour...

Comment: can you produce a database query that you want to achieve?

Comment: Give us some small data sample (partner, visit) and your result expectation.

Comment: @netik more info attached... any ideas? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options:

1) If you are not pinned to Critera api, I recommend to use HQL instead of Criteria API

```
Date d =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-10-12");
Query query = session.createQuery("select count(*) from Visit v where trunc(v.date)=:date and v.visitor.id=:visitorId");
query.setParameter("date", d);
query.setParameter("visitorId", 1L);
Long count =  (Long) query.uniqueResult();
```

2) If you want to use Criteria API, it's possible to apply sqlRestriction. Unfortunately you will lock to specific database.
This example works on HSQLDB

```
Date d =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-10-12");
Long count = (Long) session.createCriteria(Visit.class)
           .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
           .add(Restrictions.eq("visitor.id", 1L))
           .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(date)=?", d, org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE))
           .uniqueResult()  ;
```

3) It's also possible to use pure criteria API, but date restriction must be a little bit hacked (using between restriction)

```
Date d =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-10-12");
Date maxDate = new Date(d.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
Long count = (Long) session.createCriteria(Visit.class)
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                .add(Restrictions.eq("visitor.id", 1L))
                .add(Restrictions.between("date", d, maxDate))
                .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: sorry for late answer @netik

Comment: I'm trying to use first option, but i get a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` cause does not recognice `trunc` ...

Answer (score 1):

Well... finally, after almost getting crazy, I've found solution to my query using @netik first solution with some modifications: I've found out problem was `mysql` was not supporting `trunc` . No matter `hql` does.

So finally the query method after data processing is like that:

```
public Integer getPartnerVisitDatesSinceDate(Date startDate, Long partnerId) {
    Query query = getSession().createQuery("select count(distinct visit.date) from Visit visit where date(visit.date) >= :date and visit.visitor.id = :visitorId");
    query.setDate("date", startDate);
    query.setParameter("visitorId", partnerId);
    return (Integer) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Thanks @netik!